# Chromium build in Android Studio - /_all/build/intermediates/compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, chromium

I'm trying to build gradle project from chromium source code using official guide.
I have followed instructions from this page https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md and that was succesful.

After that I have tried following this instructions

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md

and running this script

**build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Default**

generated the project with some duplicated dependencies. I have commented dependencies that caused duplication but than I got this error.

**/_all/build/intermediates/compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar (No such file or directory)**

Does anyone know what can be a problem?

Comment: did you found any solutions for the same ?

Comment: @SanketKachhela No, I gave up trying. I'll try again when google update guide for building chromium, if that ever happen.